# Ver valor en ventana modal con asp.net vb.net y boostrap

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap, vb.net, modal

Quiero abrir una ventana modal con `boostrap` en `asp.net` pero que me cambie el valor de un `label` que está en el cuerpo del modal para eso hago esto

**ASP.net**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <Asp:label/ id text>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**VB.net codebehind**

```
Idlbl.text = "error en usuario inténtelo de nuevo"
```

No se me ocurre alguna otra forma de cambiar el `label` según el evento del usuario.

Comment: Puedes poner parte de tu código?, esto lo puedes hacer con javaScript... no necesitas codebehind

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, lo que veo según el codigo que subiste, es que el control label está mal formado :

```
<asp:label Id="Idlbl" runat="server" text="" />
```

Aunque no se si sea un simple error de transcripcion en la pregunta.

Saludos,